# MySql issue on playapps

Tags: mysql, playframework

I have deployed my play! application on http://www.playapps.net/.

All seemed to start OK but for some reason my queries are not working.

I have imported my script from local to their server and even I have the error:
`Access denied for user 'play'@'localhost' to database 'da'` (but it created my tables into their play schema there and imported my data).

Can this error be an issue for my not displaying data from DB?

Because I see no error in the logs.

Is here anybody who deployed app on this hosting solution and had this error also?

**UPDATE**: I've solved the above error, so now the import of my tables is done directly in play database. I log in with ssh user, open mysql console and I can see the tables.

But still, the query from my site is returning empty results. And locally it works perfectly.

Do I need any other configuration apart of this?

```
%playapps.application.mode=prod
%playapps.application.log=INFO
%playapps.db=mysql:play:play@play
%playapps.jpa.ddl=update
```

Answer (score 2):

Very ugly situation.

My tables were not with capital letters. Play was looking for "Magazine" table (it created it but was empty) and I had also "magazine" table populated.

Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Ps: what was quite strange was that locally, on windows it worked.

Comment: Windows is case insensitive : http://superuser.com/questions/165975/are-all-versions-of-windows-case-insensitive

Comment: If you hadn't already; I always prefer to add a `@Table(name = "MY_NAME")` annotation to model entities, just to avoid this kind of situation. That way I'm sure that the schema that gets created is named according to the rules I have defined, rather than what Hibernate decides the names should be. Good find, though.

Comment: also, don't use %playapps.jpa.ddl=update
 in production. Any ddl modification in production may cause problems in the long term